# Error check macro that calls function in destructor

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using an external C API from C++, where functions report an error by setting a global error state that needs to be queried manually after each function call.

In order to avoid doing this manually each time I'm using a macro to wrap the function calls, which looks similar to this:

```
#define CHECK(_call_) \
    do { \
        _call_; \
        int err = LastError(); \
        if(err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while(0)
```

used like `CHECK(ExternalFct(1, 2, 3))`.

But this does not work for functions that return a value. In order to support this, a solution that seemed to work is to create and call a temporary lambda, containing an object that checks the error in its destructor:

```
#define CHECK(_call_) \
    ([&] { \
        struct ErrorChecker { \
            ~ErrorChecker() noexcept(false) { \
                int err = LastError(); \
                if(err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            } \
        } errorChecker; \
        return _call_; \
    }())
```

It uses the fact that `return <expression>` is allowed even if the expression is void.

This seems to work, but looks like it could cause problems, mainly due to the capture-all lambda (needed to allow local variables inside the *call* expression), and the destructor which throws exceptions.

Are there situations in which this construct would cause problems (or unnecessary overhead), and is there a better way to make a single `CHECK()` macro that would work with both void and non-void functions?

Comment: How big is the C-API (how many functions are there?).  If it's modest then writing a proper C++ class wrapping the API would be a better bet.  Using crafty macros often ends in tears.

Comment: I think this is good variant without overhead and much of problems. Exceptions in destructors discouraged only because of possibbility to throw exception when you already handling exception. This is not the case in your case.

Comment: @sklott: I don't know how you proved that this doesn't throw an exception during unwinding.  It all depends on where the `CHECK` macro is used.

Comment: @BenVoigt OP stated that he calls C API, the only unwinding can occur if called function throwed exception, but C functions can't throw exceptions.

Comment: @sklott: what about `MyClass::~MyClass() { CHECK( my_C_cleanup_function(this->descriptor) ); }`

Comment: @BenVoigt This issue is independent from implementation of `CHECK()` and we were talking about this implementation.

Comment: @BenVoigt that has the potential to `throw` from a destructor, which would be very bad.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Exactly.  Another comment claimed one didn't need to worry about it, while I said it can be a problem, depending on where the `CHECK` macro is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your variant better, but if you want to get rid of destructor, you can do:

```cpp
#define CHECK(_call_) \
    ([&]<typename T = decltype(_call_)> { \
        if constexpr (std::is_void_v<T>) { \
            _call_; \
            int err = LastError(); \
            if(err != 0) throw Error{err, __FILE__, __LINE__}; \
            return; \
        } else { \
            T result = _call_; \
            int err = LastError(); \
            if(err != 0) throw Error{err, __FILE__, __LINE__}; \
            return result; \
        } \
    }())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with macros, I would suggest renaming `CHECK()` to something more like `CHECK_NO_RETURN()`, and then defining a separate macro to handle `return`s, ie:

```
#define CHECK_NO_RETURN(_call_) \
    do { \
        _call_; \
        int err = LastError(); \
        if(err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while(0)    

#define CHECK_THEN_RETURN(_call_) \
    do { \
        auto ret = _call_; \
        int err = LastError(); \
        if(err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        return ret; \
    } while(0)
```

```
CHECK_NO_RETURN(ExternalFct1(1, 2, 3));
CHECK_THEN_RETURN(ExternalFct2(1, 2, 3));
```

Otherwise, I would suggest changing `CHECK()` into a variadic template function instead, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename R, typename... Args>
inline typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<R>::value, R>::type
Check(R (&call)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    R ret = call(args...);
    int err = LastError();
    if (err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return ret;
}

template<typename... Args>
inline void Check(void (&call)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    call(args...);
    int err = LastError();
    if (err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

```
Check(ExternalFct1, 1, 2, 3);
return Check(ExternalFct2, 1, 2, 3);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xMHtWU)

Alternatively, in C++17 and later:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename R, typename... Args>
inline auto Check(R (&call)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<R>)
    {
        R ret = call(args...);
        int err = LastError();
        if (err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        call(args...);
        int err = LastError();
        if (err != 0) throw Error(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/LuFucV4Vn)

Comment: `auto ret = call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` probably is unhappy with a `void` type?

Comment: @BenVoigt That is easily worked around by using SFINAE ([demo](https://ideone.com/xMHtWU)) or `if constexpr` ([demo](https://onlinegdb.com/LuFucV4Vn)). I have updated my answer.